# Xamarin Forms oncreate bundle null reference error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a simple Xamarin Forms app, but it says bundle is null oncreate.

At line:
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

The full error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.GetEMDKManager(Android.App.Application.Context, this);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

    }
```

It worked a few hours ago. I don't see any changes that can cause this. How should I find the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution and recompile from zero? Also, have you tried to reboot your computer?

Comment: I have tried those, but I found the error, finally. You can see the "Answer"....

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it!

Somehow I checked "Linking" to SDK Assemblies Only from None. This was the error. I checked it to None and it works again!